# Web campaign attribution to app install

Tags: google-analytics, deep-linking, firebase-analytics

Let's take Quora as an example.

```
People search stuff in Google, and hit Quora link and read the article. 

There's a banner that lets you install Quora app.
```

I'd like to know How many installs are achieved like the above (google-search => Quora web => Quora app install) (Suppose Quora is my site, I wish!)

I guess it'd be also beneficial if I could somehow recognize the utm/etc associated with the link that directed the user to my website in the first place.

Is there a tool for this stuff? Or should I implement it myself modifying my website source?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, Google Analytics for Firebase can't directly track app installs, but you can refer to the the first_open event which will be logged or triggered when a user launches the for the first time after installing or uninstalling it.

GA4F can automatically tracks conversions from its partner Ad Networks. See the list [here](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics/partners/).

What you'll need to do is to mark the events (as conversion in the console) that you'd like to track. Then, in the Conversion console (previously Attribution), go to network settings and add the Ad Network. Use the generated link as your campaign URL.

So, if the user clicks on the campaign and it generates or logs the event(s) that you'd like to track, GA4F should record the conversions for it. To see the metrics, go to console > Conversions > Conversion Events > select the event.

On the other hand, what if the Ad Network is not a partner? Or, if you'd like to use a custom campaign? GA4F can still track conversions, but you'll need to use UTM parameters.

Note: make sure that the Analytics SDK is properly integrated. Use the [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) console to double check that your implementation is working fine.

For more information, see the following helpful links:

- Firebase Help - [Attribution](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en)
- Firebase Blog - [Understanding Attribution in Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/understanding-attribution-in-firebase.html)

Comment: so if I create a link with UTM which directs users to my website. I should store it somewhere like cookie. Then when user clicks 'install' link, i'll have to add on the UTM I stored to the install link. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) is only for mobile apps. If you'd like to track conversions of your website, then use Google Analytics (GA). Feel free to ask more questions.